# SQL Server error - the server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:3300000001

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL CE v4 and following @[JuneT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2046598/junet)'s [article](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/) which talks about using v4 for syncing.

I have all the sync code written but it fails when I'm trying to provision the SQL Server scope on the line:

```
if (!scopeProvisioning.ScopeExists(ScopeName))
{
   ...
}
```

> The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:3300000001. 
>   The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session.

I have restarted the MSSQL service and the machine the server is on to no avail. `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT`returns 0.

This is not a v3.5 vs. v4 issue as the same thing was happening with the v3.5 SDF prior to me upgrading it to v4 in a futile attempt to solve this issue.

If I change the name of the scope the error changes to:

> The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:3400000001.
>   The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session.